# Получить файл в byte

Tags: php

Подскажите преобразовать нужный файл в папке сайта в byte и при нужном POST запросе передать эти byte

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

if (isset($_POST["ya_nuzhniy_zapros"]) && $_POST["ya_nuzhniy_zapros"] == "da")
{
    header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
    header('Content-Type: text/plain'); // TODO auto detect
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="file.txt"');
    header('Expires: 0');
    header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
    header('Pragma: public');
    header('Content-Length: ' . filesize('file.txt'));
    readfile('file.txt'); // yes, it echos to response
}
```

p.s. если что, можно оставить только заголовки Content-Type и Content-Length